# UITableView Question?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have a simple `UITableView` setup, but I want each item to contain an image. So when you click on an item is goes to a image. How do you think I would do this? I have about 10 items in my list(array) that will in the TableView.

Comment: You mean u want to add an image to each row and when that particular row is selected, the corresponding image should open up ?

Answer (score 1):

The [UITableViewDataSource Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) is a must read. Once the protocol has properly been implemented, using the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is your answer. Depending on your implementation requirements, this answer could vary slightly but the protocol remains the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a UITableViewCell subclass.

http://zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/

This gives you almost what you need.

Comment: No need for custom `UITableViewCell`. He can use standard cell style which holds image and title or add simple UIImageView as a subview to standard in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: I was under the impression that he needed something more than just the default. Hmm. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, add a navigation controller to handle switching between the tableview and the image.

Then overwrite the tableview method :didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theViewControllerContainingTheImage animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the items in the tableview and in the Array 
After that use this in the **didselectrowAtIndexPath** delegate of UITableView
**[myImageView setimage:[picArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]];**